# Using PHP to write query string values to a .txt file and save

Tags: php, query-string

I am able to take the values from a URL's query string and store them in some variables, however I would also like to print or write these values to a single line in a .txt document, and save that document in a given directory on the server.

Each time the page is loaded with a new query string, a new line will be added to that .txt file with the string values, and the file re-saved.

Can this be done? Struggling to find answers to this in my searches.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: _Can this be done?_ Yes. Update your question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php - try googling it first

Comment: I don't understand how coming here asking that question is any quicker than going to php.net and searching the same thing?

Comment: @Egg: I hope OP does not delete the question shortly - easy 40 points up to now :)

Comment: @Jan True, of course I'm bitter you beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Egg: But the downvotes are coming even faster - NO! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$url_value = "This is some value\n";
file_put_contents("/your/filename/here.txt", $url_value, FILE_APPEND );
```

See [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for more information.